# How to parse a php message with Java - incorrect HTTP format issue

Tags: java, php, android, json, file-upload

I'm following this tutorial.

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

If you follow the tutorial, I've saved the fileUpload.php to my server.

http://68.169.50.115/AndroidFileUpload/fileUpload.php

And this is message. I've received in JSON format when you've "successfully" saved the picture to the server. Problem is the link doesn't work, nor does the file picture actually save to my server.

```
    private void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                });

        Log.d("OGG", "JSON: " + message);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

This is the response from the Log.d, the JSON message formed by the picture.

03-13 16:40:24.725: D/OGG(5158): Link: {"error":false,"message":"File uploaded successfully!","file_path":"http://68.169.50.115/AndroidFileUpload/IMG_20150313_164010.jpg"}

It says that the picture exists but if you try the link..

http://68.169.50.115/AndroidFileUpload/IMG_20150313_164010.jpg

It doesn't work.

Is it not working properly because I have the php file saved on my cloud server and not on my personal computer like the tutorial dictates?

Why is the file not actually saving.

Here's the the file upload.php

```
<?php



// Path to move uploaded files
$target_path = "uploads/";

// array for final json respone
$response = array();

// getting server ip address
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

// final file url that is being uploaded
//$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/';

$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . 'AndroidFileUpload' . '/';


if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);


// reading other post parameters
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$website = isset($_POST['website']) ? $_POST['website'] : '';



 try {
 // Throws exception incase file is not being moved


 if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 // make error flag true
 $response['error'] = true;
 $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
}


 // File successfully uploaded
 $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
 $response['error'] = false;

 $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
 } catch (Exception $e) {
 // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
 $response['error'] = true;
   $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
 }
} else {
 // File parameter is missing
$response['error'] = true;
 $response['message'] = 'Not received any file!F';
}

// Echo final json response to client
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work.  Take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the turorial to work.  It was a bit of a challenge getting it to work with Android Studio.

The last issue I ran into was that the folder permissions on the "uploads" folder need to be set with Write permission for Group and Public.
So, I would guess that is probably the issue you're running into as well.

I also used the modified PHP code from below.

The PHP code as is will return a success response if the move_uploaded_file() call fails but does not throw an exception.  Someone commented on this in the tutorial as well.

Try this and see if you still get a success response: Move the success section to an else block so that it doesn't get called on a failure case:

```
 try {
 // Throws exception incase file is not being moved

  if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
   // make error flag true
   $response['error'] = true;
   $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
  } else {

    // File successfully uploaded
    $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
    $response['error'] = false;

    $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
  }
 } catch (Exception $e) {
   // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
   $response['error'] = true;
   $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
 }
} else {
 // File parameter is missing
 $response['error'] = true;
 $response['message'] = 'Not received any file!F';
}
```

Comment: 03-13 17:42:27.325: D/OGG0(15138): Link: {"error":true,"message":"Could not move the file!"} now it says the file is not actually moved? So the whole tutorial doesn't work?

Comment: Just use the tutorial as a loose guide.  He got it working in one environment, there will always be some variation in your environment.  Are you using Eclipse or AndroidStudio?

Comment: Eclipse. Someone else left an answer but they deleted it. When I change the PHP to the way you suggested, it says the file is not moved..

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working. Would you mind taking the php that I've posted and edit it. I see that you're copying the try and catch block before the echo json_enocde method. I'm trying it but i'm still getting an error saying the file could not be moved. You tried the tutorial and got it to work?

Comment: I got it to work one time.. but then it stopped working.. :(  I changed the permissions of the file to the right order.. and then I saw the file on my server.. but then.. i start changing stuff and broke it..

Comment: Nice! At least now you know your code works! Maybe you could delete the folder and re-create it, and get it back to the state it was when it worked.

Comment: i changed the permissions and then they changed them selves i was only able to save something one time..

Comment: Are you using a server that you pay for or a free service?

Comment: upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 50M
max_input_time = 300
max_execution_time = 300 i was missing this parameter.. but i can't still upload 12 megapixel pictures.. I'm using a samsung g5 - i can upload a 6m, 8m, 9m, but the file doesn't move with 12m. or 16m..